# Past perfect vs simple past in "It had happened just after the Taliban took over Mazar"

Tags: past-perfect

I have a question on past perfection usage.

I found this sentence from "The Kite Runner" 299p:

> I had read about the Hazara massacre in Mazar-i-Sharif in the papers.
> It had happened just after the Taliban took over Mazar, one of the last cities to fall.

Should the sentence be like below?

==> It happened just after the Taliban had taken over Mazar.

Is the event that "Taliban takes over Mazar" older than "it happened"?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: It's the _past perfect_ tense, not _perfection_! The story is told in the past tense,  Both the massacre and his reading about it in the newspaper had happened before the time he is talking about.